# Discord.py: How to go through channel history and search for a specific message?

Tags: discord.py

Essentially, I want the bot to go through the channel's message history, find a message containing some particular text, and then give out the link to the message in the same channel.

Going through the documentation, I imagine I will make use of `async for message in channel.history(params)` but I cannot figure out how for my particular use case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're on the right track, you can use [`channel.history`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.history) to get the messages. Then just compare your keyword with the message content and use [`jump_url`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.jump_url) to get the link to that message.

```py
@client.command()
async def keyword(ctx, *, word: str):
    channel = client.get_channel(730839966472601622)
    messages = await ctx.channel.history(limit=200).flatten()

    for msg in messages:
        if word in msg.content:
            print(msg.jump_url)
```

Comment: Thank you! I had a basic follow-up question: If I set oldest_first=True, and put a limit, what will it mean? Will it search the 200 oldest messages in the channel and give the oldest matching message from those, or will it search the last 200 messages and give the oldest from *them*?

Comment: If `True` it will return the oldest 200 messages (top-bottom), if `False` it will return the newest 200 messages (bottom-top)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `async for msg in ctx.channel.history(...)`

Comment: Why getting channel in `channel = client.get_channel(730839966472601622)` and then not use it?

Comment: you do use it in the next line @LucG

Comment: I think I use `ctx.channel` and not the `channel` variable