# Discord.py: How would I get a random message from the server?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

If I wanted to implement a command for my bot (using Discord.py) which would retrieve a random message from the server (the command would then prompt the user to guess who the original message author is), how might I go about doing that?  I could get a random channel, but I'm not sure how I would grab a random message from that channel once I know which channel I want to pull from.  I would have to retrieve a list of every message from the entire history of that channel, which would be very time consuming to do every time the command is used.  I guess I could store all the message ids from the entire server in a list in the code, and I could update the list on a new thread every 15 or 30 minutes or so, but I feel like this is still an inefficient option, and I have no idea how long it could take to retrieve potentially hundreds of thousands of messages per channel.  Is there any better option here, or is that about it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63863871/discord-py-how-to-go-through-channel-history-and-search-for-a-specific-message)

Comment: Sorry, it's related. But you answer can still be found there

Comment: I tried that, but it only retrieved 100 messages.  I want every single message from the channel history.  I did not specify a limit.

Comment: Because the default value is 100 messages, if want to get **all** messages, you have to set the limit to `None`, have in mind that this will take a huge amount of time to fetch.

Comment: [Read the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.history) for more information on this.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

The first is to use a database of some sort, where you store every message as it is sent. The second is fetching every single message in every single channel through [Guild.text_channels](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild%20text_channels#discord.Guild.text_channels) and [TextChannel.history()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=history#discord.TextChannel.history)

I'm going to assume you don't want to use a database.

Basically, you would need to iterate over ever text_channel of the guild, and then for each channel calls .history(limit=None) on it. (Please note, this can take a very, very, very long time to do.) Then you can call random.choice() on the resulting list of messages, and then send that message.

Here is an example:

```py
all_messages = []

for channel in ctx.guild.text_channels:
  async for message in channel.history(limit=None):
    all_messages.append(message)

message_to_send = random.choice(all_messages)
await ctx.send(message_to_send.system_content)  # see note below
```

Note: I always use message.system_content instead of message.content, because system_content will work for join messages too. Both are fine, however.

This would work, but would take a ridiculously long time to achieve. I would recommend keeping the limit to something under 500, or maybe even using the `around` kwargs of history(). You could do something like this:

1. Choose a random date between now and the creation of this server
2. Call .history() with around=the_random_date
3. Keep the limit to 100

In fact, if I were to ever make a command like this, this is the *only* way I would ever do it.

Comment: You can also choose a  random channel get random message - Or - random channel around a random date

Comment: @12944qwerty problem there is that some channels are newer, so if I choose a random date near the beginning of the server creation, there's a good chance the random channel I choose won't have any messages around that time.

Comment: True, But it's still an option ;)